# How to set up a height for a <div> in responsive css designs?

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to make a responsive website. My issue is if i am not setting a div height then the bottom of the div content has come up and overlay with the top div contents. Also if I sets a height, when i see it in responsive it takes the full height and show white space. Can you guys please sort it out?

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: We're not code sample generators. Have you tried something or you're expecting us to do your some kind of homeworks ? Show us your code at least

Comment: Please check my code below.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
<div style="height:20%"> CONTENT </div>
```

or

```
<div style="height:40px"> CONTENT </div>
```

use % to specify the amount of space your div will get in your current container or px for the number of pixels

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Friends, this is my sample coding

```html
 

    <div class="row clearfix">
 <div class="left-banner">
     <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="right-banner">
     <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <p></p>
</div>
```

> CSS part:

```css
.row{width:100%;}
.left-banner{float:left; width:60%;}
.right-banner{float:right; width:40%; display:none;}
.container{width:100%;}
```

> For mobile responsive, I want to hide the right banner div so I did 'display: none;' but the container div came up and overlay with the row div. I just want to hide the right banner without any affect of other divs.